# How to set object variable from async callback

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I just started with creating custom objects in javascript. I want to set `this.someObjVar` using code below, but something wrong in my approach. Maybe async response uses it's own scope or thread.

```
// The code below used like:
someClass = new extfoo.SomeClass();
someClass.loadArrFromFile();
// this will be called far later after async returns
someClass.showSomeObjVar();

extfoo.js
=========
var extfoo = {};

extfoo.SomeClass = function() {
  this.someObjVar = [];
  this.showSomeObjVar = extfoo.showSomeObjVar;
  this.loadArrFromFile = extfoo.loadArrFromFile;
};
// Bad results here
extfoo.showSomeObjVar = function() {
  // results '0'
  console.log('showSomeObjVar: ' + this.someObjVar.length);
};

// Async array population
extfoo.loadArrFromFile = function() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
      this.someObjVar = xhr.responseText.split('\r\n')
      // results '23' elements
      console.log("someObjVar length: "+this.someObjVar.length);
    }
  }
  // request code ...
};
```

Comment: Is `loadArrFromFile` a member of `SomeClass.prototype`? The code at the top suggests that it is, but the only assignment I see is `extfoo.loadArrFromFile`. Also keep in mind that the value of `this` will change inside the `xhr.onreadystatechange` callback, so `this.someObjVar = xhr.resp...` won't be the same reference that you have directly within the `loadArrFromFile` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you certain that `this.someObjVar` is referencing `extfoo`?

There's a chance that the `this` object in the `extfoo.loadArrFromFile` function is referencing the function itself (`xhr.onreadystatechange`), and not the `extfoo` object:

```
extfoo.loadArrFromFile = function() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {

      //I'm going to create a new variable for this function called this.someObjVar
      //Cause I don't know about extfoo's.
      this.someObjVar = xhr.responseText.split('\r\n')
      // results '23' elements
      console.log("someObjVar length: "+this.someObjVar.length);

      //Whup, end of the line, I guess I'll just forget about that variable I just made.
    }
  }
  // request code ...
};
```

There are several ways to fix this, but to test, try changing `this` in the `extfoo.loadArrFromFile` function to `extfoo`.

Here's how to fix it:

```
extfoo.loadArrFromFile = function() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {

      //OOOH you mean that object
      extfoo.someObjVar = xhr.responseText.split('\r\n')
      // results '23' elements
      console.log("someObjVar length: "+extfoo.someObjVar.length);

    }
  }
  // request code ...
};
```

One last thing... is `extfoo.SomeClass.someObjVar` supposed to be different from `extfoo.someObjVar`? This code will work if that's the case, but otherwise, you'll want to include a `SomeClass` in between each reference.

Comment: You are right, but how to pass the reference to current someClass instance?

Comment: Updated the answer with a solution

Answer (score 0):

Well since it's an asynchronous request, someClass.loadArrFromFile() will not wait until the request is complete, so someClass.showSomeObjVar() will be called before it's complete.

You could add a termination handler to handle the results:

```
extfoo.loadArrFromFile = function(done) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
      this.someObjVar = xhr.responseText.split('\r\n')
      // results '23' elements
      console.log("someObjVar length: "+this.someObjVar.length);
      done();
    }
  }
```

You could then do something like this:

```
someClass.loadArrFromFile(function() {
  someClass.showSomeObjVar();
});
```

Comment: True, except that the question states `// this will be called far later after async returns` referring to `showSomeObjVar()`, so if this is to be believed, then the async issue would be covered.

Comment: Sorry, I've added that comment after a minute after first post

Comment: If your request is indead async, then the loadArrFromFile will return before the request is complete because javascript is not multithreaded. So when you do xhr.send() it will not wait for a response from the server, but will continue to execute the code that follows. The onreadystatechange function will be called later (by the same thread).